# In what context(s) can "said" (in the sense of "mentioned earlier") be used?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

For example, "The crime was committed at 7:42pm. The suspect was in the area at said time" or "I hereby give notice to end my tenancy at 1234 Fake Street. I will no longer be living at said address next year".

Is this word used primarily in legalese?

Comment: It is only used in legalese, and is rarely warranted ... you can almost always say the same thing quite clearly without resort to this term.

Comment: Said term can appear in many contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Legalese is this word's natural environment. However, it can be used in any context, including romantic poetry.